# sqoop started but command show sqoop command not found

Tags: sqoop

i am learning sqoop from few days and successfully installed and configure with hadoop.

```
hadoop_usr@sawai-Lenovo-G580:/usr/local/sqoop/bin$ sqoop2-server start
Setting conf dir: /usr/local/sqoop/bin/conf
Sqoop home directory: /usr/local/sqoop
The Sqoop server is already started.
hadoop_usr@sawai-Lenovo-G580:/usr/local/sqoop/bin$ sqoop
sqoop: command not found
```

sqoop server is already running and when i try to fire sqoop command then i get error message. `command not found`. sqoop home is already in path

```
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
export HADOOP_INSTALL=$HADOOP_HOME

export SQOOP_HOME=/usr/local/sqoop
export SQOOP_CONF_DIR=$SQOOP_HOME/conf
export SQOOP_CLASSPATH=$SQOOP_HOME/server/lib
export PATH=$PATH:$SQOOP_HOME/bin:$SQOOP_CONF:$SQOOP_CLASSPATH
```

> 

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin:/usr/local/hadoop/bin:/usr/local/sqoop/bin::/usr/local/sqoop/server/lib
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: not seeing anything for `JAVA_HOME` and its path could you please check and that Java is installed and its path is set correctly

Comment: @SandeepSingh  is this possible that sqoop server is started without java path?

Answer (score 0):

`command not found` error in most of the cases happens because of path is not set for same.

Kindly set the paths of `sqoop`, which you already have done.
*export PATH=$PATH:$SQOOP_HOME/bin:$SQOOP_CONF:$SQOOP_CLASSPATH*

Compile the file where you have set **$PATH** or restart your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

put below command in .bashrc file

```
export SQOOP_HOME=/home/pj/sqoop 
export PATH=$PATH:$SQOOP_HOME/bin
```

and restart .bashrc

```
source .bashrc
```

If still issue persist, restart terminal.